# ECharts bar chart backed by dataset; tooltip with several values

Tags: echarts

I'd like to show bar chart with categories on x-axis (say months), multiple series and each bar element containing multiple data points (value shown on y-axis, the rest in tooltip).

It's relatively easy to do it using `series.data`:

```
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      // Use axis to trigger tooltip
      type: 'shadow' // 'shadow' as default; can also be 'line' or 'shadow'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Series A',
      type: 'bar',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      data: [
        ['Jul', 320, 2], 
        ['June', 119, 4]],
      encode: {
        tooltip: [0,1,2]
      }
    }
    ,
        {
      name: 'Series B',
      type: 'bar',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      data: [
        ['Jul', 420, 3], 
        ['June', 123, 5]],
      encode: {
        tooltip: [0,1,2]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

[image: rendered graph with tooltip]

I'm wondering how it can be refactored best to use dataset? I have two ideas, I wonder what are pros & cons.. Maybe there is other, cleaner way to express it.

Ideally instead of one big array I'd prefer to have array of objects so dimensions are named.

**Solution: One dataset, shifting indices**

```
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      // Use axis to trigger tooltip
      type: 'shadow' // 'shadow' as default; can also be 'line' or 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
    //, data: ['Jul', 'June']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  dataset: {
    source: [
        ['Jul', 320, 2, 420, 3], 
        ['June', 119, 4, 123, 5]]
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Series A',
      type: 'bar',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      encode: {
        y: 1,
        tooltip: [0,1,2]
      }
    }
    ,
        {
      name: 'Series B',
      type: 'bar',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      encode: {
        y: 3,
        tooltip: [0,3,4]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

With named dimensions it would look like:

```
dataset: {
    source: [
        [month:'Jul', SeriesA_dim1: 320, SeriesA_dim2: 2, SeriesB_dim1: 420, SeriesB_dim2: 3], 
        [month:'Jun', SeriesA_dim1: 119, SeriesA_dim2: 4, SeriesB_dim1: 123 SeriesB_dim2: 5], 
  },

....

      encode: {
        y: 'SeriesB_dim1',
        tooltip: ['month','SeriesB_dim1','SeriesB_dim2']
      }
```

**Solution 2: Multiple datasets**

```
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      // Use axis to trigger tooltip
      type: 'shadow' // 'shadow' as default; can also be 'line' or 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  dataset: [{
    source: [
        ['Jul', 320, 2], 
        ['June', 119, 4]]
  },
  {
    source: [
        ['Jul', 420, 3], 
        ['June', 123, 5]]
  }],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Series A',
      type: 'bar',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      // data: [
      //   ['Jul', 320, 2], 
      //   ['June', 119, 4]],
      encode: {
        tooltip: [0,1,2]
      }
    }
    ,
        {
      name: 'Series B',
      type: 'bar',
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      // data: [
      //   ['Jul', 420, 3], 
      //   ['June', 123, 5]],
      datasetIndex: 1,
      encode: {
        tooltip: [0,1,2]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

With named dimensions it would look like:

```
  dataset: [{
    source: [
        [month:'Jul', dim1: 320, dim2: 2], 
        [month:'June', dim1: 119, dim2: 4]]
  },
  {
    source: [
        [month:'Jul', dim1: 420, dim2: 3], 
        [month:'June', dim1: 123, dim2: 5]]
  }],

....

      encode: {
        y: 'dim1', // the default would be likely working as well
        tooltip: ['month','dim1','dim2']
      }
```